# Is the Mediator must hold a view in PureMvc?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, design-patterns, puremvc

i have one question about pureMvc.

i uew pureMvc to build an engine, in the engine init part i have an requirement

1) moduleA must init firt

2) moduleB , moduleC need init after moduleA init complate.

3) moduleD need init after moduleB & moduleC init complate.

4) moduleA , moduleB , moduleC , moduleD all extends Proxy beacuse the four system all need to send notifiation ,but no need to listen it.

but to fit for the requirement i can't use command to do it , beacuse they have ini order and also they need to remember current state(ex: moudelB is init Complate but moudleC is not init complate then can't init moudleD) but command is stateless.

the best way i think is use one Mediator to do it, beacuse it can both listen and send notifiation.

my question is :

1) is this a good way to use one Mediator to do it ?

2) if use Mediator is good way, then when it hear first  moduleA is init complate

```
registerCommand(FIRST_MODULE_INIT_COMPLATE , initStepTwoCommand);
sendNotification(FIRST_MODULE_INIT_COMPLATE);
removeCommand(FIRST_MODULE_INIT_COMPLATE);
```

need to do things like that way or just do the inti logic in the Mediator ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a utility called StartUpManager, which should handle this problem. It let's you define loading dependencies so mediators/proxies aren't registered before the required data is available. Here's the link

http://trac.puremvc.org/Utility_AS3_StartupManager